# Model space from Blaschke factor

Tags: complex-analysis, hardy-spaces

Let $u$ be an inner function and denote by $H^2$ the Hardy space on the open unit disc $\mathbb{D}$.

> A model space $K_u$ associated to $u$ is a Hilbert space of the form
>   \begin{equation}
> K_u = (uH^2)^{\perp}
> \end{equation}
>   where $\perp$ denotes the orthogonal complement in $H^2$.

Let $\lambda_1 \in \mathbb{D}$. We consider $u = B_{\lambda_1}$ the Blaschke factor at $\lambda_1$ defined on $\mathbb{D}$ by $B_{\lambda_1}: z \mapsto \dfrac{\lambda_1 - z}{1 - \overline{\lambda}_1z}$. I am looking to prove that 
\begin{equation}
K_u = \text{span}\{k_{\lambda_1} \}
\end{equation}
where $k_{\lambda_1}: z \mapsto \dfrac{1}{1-\overline{\lambda}_1 z}$ is the reproducing kernel of $H^2$ at $\lambda_1$. I managed to prove that $$\text{span} \{k_{\lambda_1} \} \subset K_u$$ 
by using the reproducing property of $k_{\lambda_1}$ to obtain that for all $f \in H^2$, $$ \langle uf,  k_{\lambda_1} \rangle = u(\lambda_1)f(\lambda_1) = 0$$ (since $u(\lambda_1) = 0$). I struggle to prove the second inclusion (or to find another argument to prove the equality).

I am a beginner in this subject, so all hints and details are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was dealing with the same stuff recently (a little more general). Let me just copy my lemma here. $\mathfrak I$ is the set of inner functions.

**Lemma:**
Let $(z_j)_{j\in\mathbb N}\subset\mathbb D$ be a Blaschke sequence such that $z_i\neq z_j$ for $i\neq j$ and let $h$ be the Blaschke product with respect to $(z_j)_{j\in\mathbb N}$. Then
$$
\mathcal H_h := (hH^2)^\perp = \overline{\operatorname{span}}\{k_{z_j} : j\in\mathbb N\}.
$$
*Proof.* 
Let $f\in H^2$. Then $\langle hf,k_{z_j}\rangle = h(z_j)f(z_j) = 0$ for all $j\in\mathbb N$. Hence, $k_{z_j}\in\mathcal H_h$. Now, let $f\in\mathcal H_h$ such that $\langle f,k_{z_j}\rangle = 0$, i.e., $f(z_j) = 0$, for all $j\in\mathbb N$. Factorize $f$ as $f = uv$ with $u\in\mathfrak I$ and an outer function $v$. As $v$ has no zeros in $\mathbb D$, we have $u(z_j) = 0$ for all $j\in\mathbb N$. Hence, the Blaschke product $h$ must be a divisor of $u$, i.e., $u = hu_1$ with some $u_1\in\mathfrak I$. But this implies $f = h(u_1v)\in hH^2$ and thus $f=0$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have a question if you don't mind - why must the Blaschke factor be a divisor of $u$?

Comment: Because each inner function $f$ has a representation $f = BE$ with a Blaschke product $B$ and a "boundary function" $E$ which takes further care of the behaviour of $f$ at the boundary. It has no zeros inside the unit disk. The zeros of $f$ are exactly the zeros of $B$. Hence, if $f$ has the zeros $z_j$, then the Blaschke product defined by the $z_j$ must be a divisor of $f$.